# Establishing remote connection between a domain and workgroup computer in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to establish a Powershell remote connection to a workgroup computer from a domain joined computer. Both are on the same network. i am entering the PSSession from a admin account.

I have an admin account on the target computer, which is not as same as the admin account on the client that i am using to establish the remote connection from.

I am passing the credential of the admin account of the target computer in enter pssessionn cmdlet but couln't establish the remote connection.

I have added my local computer's ip to the trusted hosts list on the target system.i can also ping the target system. I am new to powershell , What i am doing wrong?

The error i am getting if i use the admin credential of the target system:

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server DESKTOP-XXXXXXX failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you in with this
credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If
you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.
Possible causes are:
 -The user name or password specified are invalid.
 -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
 -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
 -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
 -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
After checking for the above issues, try the following:
 -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
 -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS
transport.
Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
  -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DESKTOP-XXXXXXX -Credential Get-Credent ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DESKTOP-XXXXXXX:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Comment: Domain admin? Also what is the error your are getting?

Comment: yes, i am trying to do ps remoting from a domain admin account. when i provide the credential it gives access denied error, when i dont provide the credential it gives kerberose authentication error.

Comment: Finally resolved this. I added the FQDN of the client machine in the trusted hosts list of the remote machine. Before i had added the FQDN of the remote machine in the client machine. i changed it to just the host name of the remote machine. it is working now. strange!